# Exception Description: xxx uses a non-entity xx as target entity in the relationship attribute [method xxx]

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence

I'm getting this error while deploying the java ee app to weblogic server 12.x:

```
[11:50:07 AM] [Deployer:149034]An exception occurred for task [Deployer:149026]deploy application habib on AdminServer.: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities.SalesRepCommision] uses a non-entity [class net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities.Commission] as target entity in the relationship attribute [method getCommission]..
[11:50:07 AM] weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: [class net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities.SalesRepCommision] uses a non-entity [class net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities.Commission] as target entity in the relationship attribute [method getCommission].
```

and my commission class code is:

```
package net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

import javax.persistence.Transient;

import net.tbse.back.accounting.chartOfaccount.tree.entiteis.Account;
import net.tbse.back.inventory.salesYeas.entities.SalesYear;


@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMISSIONS")
public class Commission implements Serializable {

  private Long commissionsId;
  private Long companyId;
  private Double fromAmount;
  private Double toAmount;
  private Long percentage;
  private SalesYear salesYear;
  private Account commissionAccount;
  private String commissionAccountName;



    public Commission() {
        super();
    }

    @TableGenerator(name = "CommissionGen", table = "SEQUENCE",
                    pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
                    pkColumnValue = "COMMISSIONS")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "CommissionGen")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COMMISSION_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long getCommissionsId() {
        return commissionsId;
    }

  public void setCommissionsId(Long commissionsId) {
      this.commissionsId = commissionsId;
  }

    public void setFromAmount(Double fromAmount) {
        this.fromAmount = fromAmount;
    }

  @Column(name = "FROM_AMOUNT")
    public Double getFromAmount() {
        return fromAmount;
    }

    public void setToAmount(Double toAmount) {
        this.toAmount = toAmount;
    }

  @Column(name = "TO_AMOUNT")
    public Double getToAmount() {
        return toAmount;
    }

    public void setPercentage(Long percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

  @Column(name = "DEF_PERCENTAGE")
    public Long getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }
  @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    public Long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setSalesYear(SalesYear salesYear) {
        this.salesYear = salesYear;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SALES_YEAR_ID")
    public SalesYear getSalesYear() {
        return salesYear;
    }

  public void setCommissionAccount(Account commissionAccount) {
      this.commissionAccount = commissionAccount;
  }

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="COMMISSION_ACCOUNT_ID")
  public Account getCommissionAccount() {
      return commissionAccount;
  }

  public void setCommissionAccountName(String commissionAccountName) {
      this.commissionAccountName = commissionAccountName;
  }

  @Transient
  public String getCommissionAccountName() {

    if (isNullOrEmpty(commissionAccountName)) {

        if (getCommissionAccount() != null) {

            commissionAccountName = getCommissionAccount().getName();

        }
    }

      return commissionAccountName;
  }

  @Transient
  public boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
      return (s == null) || s.trim().equals("");
  }
}
```

and this is SalesRepComission class code:

```
package net.tbse.back.inventory.salesRep.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

import javax.persistence.Transient;

import net.tbse.back.inventory.salesYeas.entities.SalesPeriod;
import net.tbse.back.inventory.salesYeas.entities.Target;


@Entity
@Table(name = "SALES_REP_COMMISSIONS")
public class SalesRepCommision implements Serializable {

  private Long salesRepCommissionsId;
  private SalesRep saleRep;
  private Commission commission;
  private Map<Long,Target> salesPeriodCommissions = new HashMap<Long, Target>();
  private Double fromAmount;
  private Double toAmount;



    public void setSalesRepCommissionsId(Long salesRepCommissionsId) {
        this.salesRepCommissionsId = salesRepCommissionsId;
    }

  @TableGenerator(name = "SalesRepCommisionsGenerator", table = "SEQUENCE",
                  pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
                  pkColumnValue = "SALES_REP_COMMISSIONS")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "SalesRepCommisionsGenerator")
  @Id
  @Column(name = "SALES_REP_COMMISSIONS_ID", nullable = false)
    public Long getSalesRepCommissionsId() {
        return salesRepCommissionsId;
    }


    public void setSaleRep(SalesRep saleRep) {
        this.saleRep = saleRep;
    }

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "SALES_REP_ID")
    public SalesRep getSaleRep() {
        return saleRep;
    }


    public void setCommission(Commission commission) {
        this.commission = commission;
    }

    @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "COMMISSION_ID")
    public Commission getCommission() {
        return commission;
    }

    public void setSalesPeriodCommissions(Map<Long, Target> salesPeriodCommissions) {
        this.salesPeriodCommissions = salesPeriodCommissions;
    }

@Transient
    public Map<Long, Target> getSalesPeriodCommissions() {
        return salesPeriodCommissions;
    }

    public void setToAmount(Double toAmount) {
        this.toAmount = toAmount;
    }

@Column(name = "TO_AMOUNT")
    public Double getToAmount() {
        return toAmount;
    }

    public void setFromAmount(Double fromAmount) {
        this.fromAmount = fromAmount;
    }
  @Column(name = "FROM_AMOUNT")
    public Double getFromAmount() {
        return fromAmount;
    }
}
```

and this is the persistance.xml file:

[persistance.xml](https://gist.github.com/alihabbash/9c61520d693d500e4bdf5d975b672068)

also, I have checked **persistence.xml** and the class is included correctly with the same package.
the compile process is finished successfully and produced a jar file.

Can someone help me with this? There is certainly an error in here somewhere, but i cannot find it.

Comment: Show the code of *SalesRepCommision*.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the class *Commission* is not declared as *@Entity*. Show its code.

Comment: The class *Commission* look OK. Show you *persistence.xml*.

Comment: I would remove mappings from *persistence.xml* and would use annotations only.